# Why can't this port be accessed outside of the local machine?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a node.js server running on an EC2 instance.  I can connect to my index.html page by visiting 12.345.678.900:2112 (not the actual site, just an example).  Later on, I open a socket connection that is listening on port 3113.  When I'm on the machine itself, I can access the webpage through the localhost (localhost:3113/foo).  When I try to access it outside the local machine through 12.345.678.900:3113/foo, I can't access it.  The socket connection is successful and the server is listening on 3113 when I run netstat, but it just doesn't allow me to access the page.  I have a feeling my ports may be blocked, but from what I tell it shouldn't be.  I don't have this problem when I run this server on my local machine however.

[Incoming Connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPm2J.png)

Solution:

Since curl was telling me port 3113 wasn't open, but it wasn't being blocked on AWS I looked through my code and realized that I opened port 3113 but then closed it soon after, which meant that while I was getting a log statement telling me the port was open since it was closed almost immediately I wasn't able to access the port.

Comment: Can you clarify "The socket connection is successful"? What do you get if you run `curl -iv 12.345.678.900:3113/foo` from outside?

Comment: When I navigate to foo, I connect to another machine using a socket and I just wanted to clarify the problem wasn't that the socket connection was failing.  When I run curl command, it says connection refused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you setup TCP listening port, you had to specify IP address and port number. If your server is listening on 127.0.0.1:3113, then it won't be accessible from its external IP address. You can also specify the special 0.0.0.0 as the IP address, which indicates that you want to listen on that port in "all" IP addresses (for some definition of "all").

If your machine have multiple network interfaces (e.g. multiple network cards, or virtualised network interface), then it's possible to have the same ip address actually being on different networks and you'll have to specify the specific network interface when you listen to them. But if you did set up something unusual like that, you probably already know about these networking stuffs already. Note that if you have Docker or virtual machines, they may also creates virtual network interface for each containers/VM.

On AWS/EC2, your machine may also have internal IP address that's only accessible from your VPC and an Elastic IP which can be accessed directly from the outside world. You didn't say which "external" IP address you were using.

Finally, you may have firewall installed on the server. ipfw or iptable may have rules blocking external listening port.